# Integrating GAE Search API with Datatstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-search-api

When a document is stored into both the Cloud datastore and a Search index, is it possible when querying from the Search index, rather than returning the Search index documents, returning each corresponding entity from the Cloud datastore instead? In other words, I essentially want my search query to return what a datastore query would return.

More background: When I create an entity in the datastore, I pass the entity id, name, and description parameters. A search document is built so that its doc id is the same as the corresponding entity id. The goal is to create a front-end search implementation that will utilize the full-text search api to retrieve all relevant documents based on the text query. However, I want to return all details of that document, which is stored in the datastore entity.

Would the only way to do this be to create a key for each search doc_id returned from the query, and then use `get_multi(keys)` to retrieve all relevant datastore entities?

Comment: I guess an alternative to converting to pure Search documents is to rely only on datastore queries and recreate full-text-search type capabilities by building multiple indexes. Hoping someone has more insightful thoughts than these options.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question, it is unclear what you want answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no first class support for this, your best bet is to make the document id match the datastore key and route all put/get/search requests through a single DAO/repository tier to ensure some level of consistency.

You can use parallel Async writes to keep latency down, but there's not much you can do about search not participating in transactions. It also has no defined consistency, so assume it is eventual, and probably much slower than datastore index propagation.

Comment: If I wanted to have strongly consistent data, then would I have to resort to using only the datastore for transactions? And if so, then would I have to create my own implementation of text-based search to datastore queries?

Comment: If you want strongly consistent queries, you must use ancestor queries within the datastore. You can stem and fragment terms yourself and store them in the datastore, this is pretty much what the search service does.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any information that you need in the Search API documents, in addition to their text content.

This will allow you to retrieve all data in one call at the expense of, possibly, storing some duplicate information both in the Search API documents and in the Datastore entities. Obviously, having duplicate data is not ideal, but it may be a good option for rarely changing data (e.g. document timestamp, author ID, title, etc.) as it can offer a significant performance boost.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you would go about storing objects like datastore keys? The Search API doesn't seem to have support for this data type. I only ask because some of the values in the datastore are ndb KeyProperties which refer to other entities, so transferring these types of data to the Search API doesn't seem like a feasible option.

Comment: I prefer to store entity IDs instead of keys as they take much less space, but if you prefer/need to store keys, any datastore key can be turned into a string and then back - there are standard methods for such conversions.

Comment: This only works for some data - recall that the search service only supports dates, not times, and there are precision and scale limitiations on numbers that prevent you storing many numbers, for example longs. The Search API really isn't suitable as a data store except in specific cases - that may be ok for you or it may not

Comment: @Nick - You can turn time into an ISO string as well, and the Search API itself uses "time when created" as a default rank for documents. I would certainly not recommend to use Search API as a substitute for the Datastore, but sometimes storing a couple of fields with the documents can be useful.  I prefer to use the Datastore for search because it allows me to implement partial word searches.